# Is $X_t := W_t^2$ a Wiener process for a Wiener process $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm studying for exam and found this exercise which I don't really understand:

Suppose $W_t$ is standard Wiener process. Is process $X_t=W_t^2, t\geq0$ a Wiener process?

So I need to show that $W_t^2$ is Gaussian and has properties of Wiener process?

Comment: Yes you have to prove that - and what did you try to prove this?

Comment: 1) $EX_t=E(W_t^2)=0$
2) $Cov(X_t,X_s)=Cov(W_t^2,W_s^2)=min(t^2,s^2)\neq min(t,s)$ so it is not Wiener process?

Comment: "$E(X_t)=E(W_t^2)=0$" ???

Comment: OK $E(W_t^2)=t$, but why? $EW_t^2=EW_tW_t=min(t,t)$?

Comment: Because W is a Wiener process, amongst ten reasons.

Comment: @Did what do you mean? Does it have to do with Gaussian properties and vector multiplications?

Comment: ?? How do you define a Wiener process, already?

Answer (score 2):

For any Wiener process $(B_t)_t$, we have $B_t \sim N(0,t)$; in particular $\mathbb{P}(B_t < 0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Since $X_t= W_t^2 \geq 0$ is non-negative, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_t<0)=0$ and therefore $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ cannot be a Wiener process.