# Proving if $W(t)$ is a weiner process, then $W^2(t)$ is also a Weiner process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm trying to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296419/154124):

For a stochastic process to be a Weiner Process it must have these properties:

1. $W(0) = 0$ so $W^2(0) = 0$
2. $E(W(t)) = 0$ but $E(W^2(t)) = t$ I think this is enough to prove that $W^2(t)$ is not a Weiner process

But I also want to prove the following:

3. $W^2(u) - W^2(t)$ is indepedent from $W^2(s) - W^2(r)$ given $u > t > s > r > 0$

In a Winer process the increments are normally distributed so to prove independence, I need to prove their covariance is $0$. But I don't know how to find if the increments for $W^2(t)$ are normally distributed or if there's another way to prove independence.

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat misleading.

Comment: As the linked question shows, $W^2(t)$ does **not** have independent increments.

Comment: @saz I randomly found the question I linked, tried to do it myself and get stuck proving the independence of the increments. I didn't know that part was already asked *facepalm*. Thanks for the link!